# Why does simple Query pull from text box but not combo box?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Simple form/subform:

[image]

When I run the query pulling from combo box  [Forms]![lastName]![Combo2]:

[image]

I get nothing, nodda, zip!

[image]

Yet if I run the query using the text box [Forms]![lastName]![txtLName]:

[image]

Works as expected:

[image]

can anyone explain this behavior - MS ACCESS 2010?

Yes....Student Table:

[image]

Comment: Does *tblStudents* contain any rows whose *LastName* equals *"Liu"* (the value displayed in the combo box)?

Comment: What does Access show for the combo box's `.Value` property?  Check in the Immediate window: `Debug.Print [Forms]![lastName]![Combo2].Value`

Comment: not sure how to do this...limited skills at this point

Comment: OK.  Use Ctrl+g to open the Immediate window.  Once there, type "`Debug.Print [Forms]![lastName]![Combo2].Value`" without the quotes in one line and press Enter at the end of that line.  Access should evaluate that statement and print a response on the next line.  What happens?

Comment: You were right on.  It was pulling the ID (column1) instead of name (column 2).  Thank you....I was at the wall on this....